# Order index based on parent model attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

My Rails app has a model `Teachers` that `belongs_to` `Users`. `Users` `has_one` `Teacher`. I'm using devise for user authentication and so the users model comes with a field: `last_sign_in_at`.

On one of my admin pages, I want to sort `Teachers` by their corresponding user's `last_sign_in_at` time. How could I achieve this?

I tried `joins` in a variety of ways, ex:

```
@teachers = User.joins(:teacher).order("users.last_sign_in_at")
```

but I haven't gotten any of them to work.

Comment: You want to get Teachers but why do you call a method from User class? Do you mean `Teacher.joins(:user)`?

Comment: @VanHuy of course. Sorry, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup the associations between your models correctly and your `teachers` table has an `user_id` column [because `Teacher` *belongs_to* `User`] in the database, then the following should work:

```
@teachers = Teacher.joins(:user).order("users.last_sign_in_at ASC")
```

or:

```
@teachers = Teacher.joins(:user).order("users.last_sign_in_at DESC")
```

Because, `User.joins(:teacher).order("users.last_sign_in_at")` will return the users, But not the teachers.

This is also given as a hint by `Van Huy`'s in the comment section.

Comment: Thank you, looks like a need a little more practice with the .joins method